# How do I do a word search without using strcmp?

Tags: c

```
int function(char * WordList[], int nSize, char * param_str)

{
  int i = 0;
    int bFlag = 0;
    
    while(i < nSize && !bFlag)
    {
        if(WordList[i] == param_str){
            return bFlag = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return bFlag;
```

i tried using strcmp and made it work [if(strcmp(WordList[i], param_str) == 0)] but im wondering whats wrong with my current code.

Comment: You are comparing two pointers, not the strings that they point at.  This is rarely useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WordList[i]` is a pointer

`param_str` is another pointer.

`WordList[i] == param_str` tests if the 2 pointers point to the same location.

What these pointers reference is not considered.  `WordList[i] == param_str` is not a *string* compare, just an address compare.

---

`strcmp(a,b)` compares the data at locations `a` and `b`.

To do the same, without `strcmp()`, form your own ...

```
int my_strcmp(const char *a, const char *b) {
  // Pseudo code
  while what `a` points to is the same as what `b` points to and `*a` is not 0
    advance both pointers
  
  return the sign of the difference of `*a` and `*b`.
}
```